# web scraping a poker game history log with python for stats

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

my goal is to find out who amongst the players at a poker game between friends on a free platform (no money involved) brings bad luck to his neighbours. In order to do so I want to scrape the game log which is accessible to anyone who has the link generated for the table with no login required. I am a beginner so this is just a fun project to learn sth new. I believe all I want can be found on the html source code of the page but I am stuck this is what I have so far using BeautifulSoup:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.pokernow.club/games/...'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"id":"main-container"})
print(containers)

[<div id="main-container">
<p class="raw-loading">Loading…</p>
</div>]
```

When I inspect the html code I can see all the info I want but when it goes through the program it is stuck on Loading.. Any pointers ? Is this completely wrong ? Thanks

Comment: Please provide full URL

Comment: this has a some log entries https://www.pokernow.club/games/R8bFDI3Wf7CZ1rSLuI_FqRPfK